# How does a linux-based operating system handle applications?

Tags: android, application

I was trying to learn how to run an application without an operating system, and I kept coming across this piece of information: In order to run a program without an operating system, that program has to provide all the oprocesses normally provided by the operating system. That got me thinking: **What are the processes an operating system like linux (such as Android) uses to run apps?**

In other words, I know that apps run inside the Os (no dip :), but I don't quite understand what functions the Os provides or how they interface with the Linux Kernel.

Advice on how to develop a program without an os is useful, but I'm mostly looking for info on how the Os manages applications. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is a really broad question.  You should look for a book or course on operating systems.  Check out some guidelines on writing your own operating system at https://superfrink.net/athenaeum/OS-FAQ/os-faq.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All processes are a line of instructions fed to the processor through memory, which can jump to other parts of memory and manipulate parts of memory as data. That's how a simplest computer works. (check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture for more info)

With modern computers you have processors that run in two different modes — **real mode** and **user mode**. When the computer starts, the first process can claim the real mode and in it, it sees the computer as it really is — with all the hardware it has.

That process is the OS kernel. What a Unix kernel does is it then starts a **user process** (the first program, usually called **init** on Unices), which has the illusion like it has the computer all for itself.

It's an illusion because the kernel will set up the hardware so that every now and then, the process will be forcibly and (to it) invisibly taken from the processor and the kernel will be let to do its managerial work for a short fraction of time. The memory the user process will see will not be real memory either, but fake memory which the kernel  maps to real hardware memory (with some hardware help, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit for more information).

The user process has no direct access to hardware but the Unix kernel presents to it a hierarchical structure for reading and writing (the **filesystem**) which the kernel translates to hardware manipulation (most simply to disk reads and disk writes but not just that). The kernel also presents couple of other services besides access to the filesystem. The user process can ask for all these services by contacting the kernel via a specified simple protocol (called a **system call**).

Two of the most fundamental services it can ask for is **forking** an **execing**. Forking asks the kernel to create another process to the image of the parent, and execing loads a new image from the file system. In this way, the initial process can start up a whole bunch of other user processes, which can then start other processes and so on.

Just like the initial process, each user child process can act as if it it was on the computer by itself, but it will be really only running on a **virtual memory** address space (which the kernel maps to real addresses behind the processes's back), and the kernel will forcibly take it out of the processor every once in a while so other processes could have their go at the processor too (this is called **pre-emptive multitasking** and the kernel has a part called the **scheduler** which is responsible for exactly how it's done).

Essentially, a kernel *multiplexes the hardware resources* (CPU, RAM, Hardrive, GPU, ...) of a computer among the user processes that have been started on it, and it does so reasonably *fairly* (each process gets a timeslice so that all processes can progress) and *efficiently* (if a process is waiting on data from a slow source (disk, network), the kernel won't waste CPU time by having it run on the CPU only to ask "is it in yet?" when the answer's logically going to be no for quite a while). All this default fairness gets adjusted with human-inputted policies. The kernel also ensures that processes can communicate with each other via various means offered by the kernel and that they get a reasonable view of the shared global state.

Comment: MIT had a nice course on OS design principles on http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm . I recommend you check it out if you're interested in this very broad topic more closely.